# catch and finally functions in angular promise wont work when using $q, but standard Promise do work - what im missing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, promise, try-catch

I'd like to know why this promises implemented with Angular $q (tested on version 1.5.3) won't execute the "catch" neither "finally" promise functions if an error is thrown (it is being catched by the outer try catch in the example below). Whereas if I do the same with the "new Promise()" it will (Im testing this in the latest version of Chrome by the way).

Run the following code where you can inject $q (like a controller) to try it for yourself. You will notice how angular promise outputs the try/catch console log (and never excecutes the finally func.) whereas the standar promise properly catches the error and runs the catch() and finally() promise functions:

```
    var angularPromise = function (data) {
        var defered = $q.defer();
        var promise = defered.promise;
        var emptyvar = null;

        if (data == "fail") {
            //generate the exception
            console.log("code reaches this point");
            var fail = emptyvar.fakeproperty;
            console.log("code will never reach this point due to the exception");
            defered.reject("failed");//neither this...
        }

        return promise;
    }

    var standardPromise = function (data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var emptyvar = null;

            if (data == "fail") {
                //generate the exception
                var fail = emptyvar.fakeproperty;
               //in this scenario this error is thrown 
               //and captured by the promise catch() 
               //just as if I would call reject() 
               //which is the expected behaviour
            }

        });
    }

    try {
        angularPromise("fail")
                .then(
                        function (success) {
                            console.log("angularPromise: oka", success)
                        }
                )
                .catch(
                        function (fail) {
                            console.log("angularPromise: fail", fail);
                        }
                ).finally(
                function (fail) {
                    console.log("angularPromise: 'finally' gets excecuted...");
                }
        );
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("angularPromise: exception catched with try/catch and not captured in promise 'catch'. Also 'finally' is never excecuted...");
    }

    try {
        standardPromise("fail")
                .then(
                        function (success) {
                            console.log(" standardPromise oka", success)
                        }
                )
                .catch(
                        function (fail) {
                            console.log("standardPromise: catched as expected", fail);
                        }
                ).finally(
                function () {
                    console.log("standardPromise: 'finally' gets excecuted...");
                }
        );
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("standardPromise exception catched outside promise", e);
    }
```

Comment: you are missing `resolve()` and `reject()` methods in your `deferred`

Comment: `//generate the exception   -> var fail = emptyvar.fakeproperty;`   Promises don't automatically wrap exceptions for you, you will need to check for them and either resolve or reject..  But if you use the new `async/await` they wrap exceptions for you.

Comment: The example is showing that the standard promise DOES capture the exception for me without the need to wrap it in a try/catch and returns as if a reject() was called, also it shows how that's is not the case when implemented using angular $q...

Comment: i deleted my answer due to it was not correct. maybe this depends on the implementation of the `Promise` object. Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Created a codepen with alerts() instead of console.logs (sorry I'm on my cell :). Take a look @messerbill https://codepen.io/panchazo/pen/GyPwOE

Comment: @FranSC, you are not truly comparing like with like. 

Whereas native promises can only be created with `new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...)`, 

Angular promises can be created with (i) `var dfrd = $q.defer(); ...; dfrd.resolve();` OR (ii) `$q(function(resolve, reject) => ...)`, similar to native Promise.

Comparison of the two promise implementations is only meaningful (well, a whole lot more meaningful) if your Angular promise is constructed with syntax (ii).

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your promise execution in a try/catch is not necessary—Angular $q's catch would catch any errors, so they would not bubble up to the catch in the try/catch.

Essentially, assuming you abstract your business logic out into a service, your service code would need to look something like this:

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('myService', function ($q) {
    function doSomething(shouldSucceed) {
      const deferred = $q.defer();

      if (shouldSucceed) {
        deferred.resolve('I succeeded! ');
      } else {
        deferred.reject('I failed! ☹️');
      }

      return deferred.promise;
    }

    return { doSomething };
  });
```

Then, your controller would call that service and handle it accordingly:

```
angular.module('app')    
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, myService)  {
    $scope.shouldSucceed = function (shouldSucceed) {
      myService
        .doSomething(shouldSucceed)
        .then(alertMessage)
        .catch(alertMessage)
        .finally(function () {
          alert('FINALLY!');
        });
    };

    function alertMessage(message) {
      alert(message);
    }
  });
```

I've made a simple view that would allow you to click buttons and toggle each message:

```
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="shouldSucceed(false)">Fail</button>
    <button ng-click="shouldSucceed(true)">Succeed</button>
  </div>
```

I have provided a working example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tinacious/pen/ddMeXP) of how to implement Angular's `$q` promises including `.then`, `.catch`, and `.finally` blocks.

Comment: "*so they would not bubble up*" - and most importantly, asynchronous errors cannot bubble *back in time* to the `try`/`catch` statement.

Comment: "Angular $q's catch would catch any errors, so they would not bubble up" -
-> actually it doesnt, that´s the whole point. Check it out by yourself: https://codepen.io/panchazo/pen/GyPwOE